# Purpose of s and cmap argument in scatter_matrix in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, iris-dataset, scatter-matrix

Exploratory Data Analysis

```python
#create df from data in X_train

#label columns using str in iris_dataset.feature_names

    iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)

#create scatter matrix from df, color by y_train

    grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize = (15,15),
                       marker = 'o', hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=60,
                       alpha=0.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

In the above code, I can't understand 's' and 'cmap' use. I know this API has been updated, but I want to learn about the use of 's' and 'cmap=mglearn.cm3' in general use.

Answer (score 1):

In plotting.scatter_matrix, 's' and 'cmap' are keyword arguments for matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.

They are optional parameters which can be used with pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.

'**s**' is used to specify the **marker size**.

'**cmap**' defines the **colormap**.

Here's a [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).